# How to get set_index first value

Tags: python

we are having only one or two cases where we have duplicate values with the set_index . Is there any way I can test if there are more than one values in "teams". if there are more than one value then I want to take first value. I am not in postion to change the index as this is to handle only a few cases.

```
    teams = df_user.set_index(['name','Email'])["Team"]
    author_team = teams[name][email]
    return author_team
```

in case of multiple values in same index, I am getting this as output. I want first value or 2nd in case of my condition.

```
Email
an.p@xx.com      01 A
an.p@xx.com     02  B
Name: Team, dtype: object
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to add the `pandas` tag when asking questions specifically about Pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby`?

```
author_team.groupby(level=0).first()
```

Or `last`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before and it throw error "author_team" is string object and cannot use groupby.--->str' object has no attribute 'groupby